# Summing Arrays by Characteristics in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to sum elements of an array by given characteristics.  For example I have 1000 draws of data, and I what I'm looking for is the sum of each draw (column) across sexes for a given year-disease (ie, the draws are by sex, year, disease, and I want the sum of both sexes for each year and disease).

```
import numpy as np
year = np.repeat((1980, 1990 , 2000, 2010), 10)
sex = np.array(['male', 'female']*20)
disease = np.repeat(('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8'), 5)
draws = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(sex.shape[0], 1000))
```

Any thoughts on how to get an array that will be shape (20, 1000) that has the sum of the draw across both sexes for a given year-disease?  I will also need to be able to do this in situations where the data isn't perfectly square (there are disease-years which only have 1 sex).

Comment: Have you seen the Pandas library, http://pandas.sourceforge.net/ ?  I don't know much about it but saw it the other day and thought it would be worth a look if I ever used labeled data.

Comment: See accepted answer to this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169240/moving-large-sql-query-to-numpy/7170135#7170135) which is directed to translating SQL queries to NumPy syntax (the query structure in your Q is in SQL "SUM ...WHERE ... ORDERBY ..., which is the query structure in the SO Question linked to in this comment),

Comment: Nowadays you probably would just use `pandas` or `numpy_groupies`: https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools   
import csv

year = np.repeat((1980, 1990 , 2000, 2010), 10)
sex = np.array(['male', 'female']*20)
disease = np.repeat(('d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4', 'd5', 'd6', 'd7', 'd8'), 5)
draws = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=(sex.shape[0], 1000))

years=np.unique(year)
diseases=np.unique(disease)

draw_sums = dict(((y,d), draws[(year==y)&(disease==d)].sum(axis=0)) 
                  for y,d in itertools.product(years,diseases))
```

This results in an dict associating each (year,disease) with the corresponding sum of the draws. To write `draw_sums` to a [csv](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python2.6/html/library/csv.html#module-csv), you could do something like this:

```
with open('/tmp/test.csv','w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['year', 'date']+['draw{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(1,1001)])
    for yeardate,draws in sorted(draw_sums.items()):
        writer.writerow(list(yeardate)+draws.tolist())
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thanks so much.  Could you tell me a good way to keep track of the years/diseases which the output "arr" corresponds to?  This produces the array, but I don't know which row corresponds to which year-disease. Thanks again.

Comment: It looks like the dictionary does a great job tracking the relationship between years/diseases and draws, but following this computation, I need to write a .csv file which has the first column as year, the second column as disease, and the following 1000 columns be the draws.  Is there a good way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again for so much input -- this has been incredibly helpful.  One last quick question:  do you have a good way to incorporate a first row which holds the titles of each column (ie, age, year, draw1... draw1000)?  I still struggle with efficient ways to get csvs in and out, and need them in such a format for presentation purposes.  Thanks again,

Comment: @mike: Writing a header is no different than writing any other row. You just pass a sequence of items to `writer.writerow`. (See above)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical group-by problem, which can be efficiently solved in a fully vectorized manner using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author)

```
keys, values = npi.group_by((year, disease)).sum(draws)
for key, value in zip(zip(*keys), values):
    print(key, value.shape)
```